# Is host name and server name the same thing?

Tags: terminology

I have seen the use of both terms. Are they the same thing or are there any differences between them?

I have seen the use of "server name" on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) and on this [Yahoo Answers page](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071201064530AAjdnGe).

Comment: Can you add some context?  Where have you seen these terms used?  They can be a bit fuzzy sometimes.  Context is everything.

Comment: @RonTrunk In this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting).

Comment: @RonTrunk Also on this [Yahoo Answers page](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071201064530AAjdnGe). But I am suspicious that in this case, it might be just an erroneous wording of the asker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hostname** is the correct term when referring to the name of a machine, as opposed to its IP address.  From Wikipedia:

> In computer networking, a hostname (archaically nodename) is a
>   label that is assigned to a device connected to a computer network and
>   that is used to identify the device in various forms of electronic
>   communication such as the World Wide Web, e-mail or Usenet.

With "server name" or "machine name" it is intended, well, the name (hostname) of the server or the machine.

Note that the hostname (e.g. `jupiter`) usually doesn't include the domain name (e.g. `example.org`). Together, they form a FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name): `jupiter.example.org`. This is the most precise usage. 
However, for instance when talking about the World Wide Web as in the Wikipedia page you linked, `jupiter.example.org` is often called (somehow incorrectly) an hostname.
In the Yahoo question you linked, they're synonyms.

Comment: So are they the same thing? What is the difference between them?

Comment: Yes, they mean the same but the term **hostname** is more correct.

Comment: Sometimes they call the whole `jupiter.example.org` as the hostname. I am guessing that this is an erroneous usage?

Comment: I edited my post. This usage is kind of incorrect but used often anyway because it's simpler.

Comment: By the way, I have one more confusion: is `networkengineering` in `networkengineering.stackexchange.com` the hostname? Then does that mean that whole `networkengineering.stackexchange.com` is located in one machine? Or not necessarily?

Comment: That's much more complicated than that :) Websites today (except very simple ones) use load balancers, multiple servers, Virtual IPs etc.

Comment: There is also the added complication when you use database servers. For example I use _hostname_ (the correct usage AFAIK) for the server. But if I need to tell people which instance to connect to I will say that the _servername_ is _hostname\sqlserverinstance_. It helps to be consistent.

Answer (score 4):

"Hostname" is used specifically in the context of the TCP/IP suite.  Other protocols or operating systems (MS Windows) often use the term "server name."  So for example, a device could be referred to by its Server Name in Windows, but by its Hostname using DNS.  The names can be different.

Often the two terms are used interchangeably.

Answer (score -3):

Switches and Routers = Hostnames = 
Device name

Systems = Server Names

DNS = FQDN

Comment: You should explain this more and give your reasoning.

Comment: You could improve your answer by editing it to add more details to make it more useful both for the original poster and future users. Typically short answers like this could provide reasoning why you believe this is the answer, more explanation about the concepts mentioned, references/links to supporting resources, or applicable examples.